# $ y' = \frac{y}{\sqrt x } , y(0) = 2 $ Existence and Uniqueness?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following first order ODE:

\begin{equation*}
y' = \frac{y}{\sqrt x },~y(0) = 2 .
\end{equation*}

Does there exist a solution? If yes, is it unique? How can I prove it by using existence and uniqueness theorem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $y'/y = 1/\sqrt x \implies \ln \frac{y}{y_0}= 2\sqrt x \implies y=2e^{2\sqrt x}$

Comment: By using Existence and Uniqueness theorem, how can i prove it?

Comment: Hint: The right hand side is not continuous at $0$, and neither is the partial w.r.t. $y$ so the existence theorem does not apply. Can you think of another solution besides the one Farnight proposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand side of the given differential equation is not even defined in the neighborhood of the initial point $(0,2)$. Therefore it is **illegal** to apply the existence and uniqueness theorem in a straightforward way. We can  say the following, however: The given ODE is allright in the halfplane $x>0$, and has the solutions $$y_c(x)=c\>e^{2\sqrt{x}},\qquad c\in{\mathbb R},$$ there. These solutions have limits $\lim_{x\to0+} y_c(x)=c$, and you can extend them as continuous functions to $x=0$. There is exactly one solution for which this extension has the value $2$ at $x=0$, namely
$$y_2(x)=2\>e^{2\sqrt{x}}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution exists and is unique for the **Existence and uniqueness theorem for Cauchy problems**, because $y(0)\neq0$.

$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Integrating on both sides, we obtain that

$$\log{|y(x)|}=2\sqrt{x}+C$$

You can now calculate the constant $C$ using the initial conditions and find $C=\log{2}$.

Solving the equation results in

$$y(x)=2e^{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: I cut short on some calculations, if you need more clarifications just ask. The solution's maximal interval of existence is $[0, +\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}$

$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$

$\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$

$\ln y=2\sqrt{x}+c$

$\ln 2 = 2\sqrt{0}+c$

$c=\ln 2$

$\ln y = 2\sqrt{x}+\ln 2$

$\ln \frac{y}{2}=2\sqrt{x}$

$y=2e^{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: By using Existence and Uniqueness theorem, how can i prove it?

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the variables and integrate $$\int_2^y \frac{dy}y = \int_0^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt x} \to ln(y/2) = 2 \sqrt x \to y = 2 e^{2\sqrt x}$$

Comment: By using Existence and Uniqueness theorem, how can i prove it?

Comment: i don't think you can use uniqueness theorem because the right hand side is not defined in any region containing $x = 0.$ i expect the solution to be unique but i can't justify yet.

Comment: For uniqueness, maybe you can do this: if $y$ and $z$ are both solutions of the Cauchy problem, then for all $x>0$ we have $|y(x)-z(x)|=\left|\int_{0}^{x}\left(y'(t)-z'(t)\right)\mathrm{d}t\right|\leq \int_{0}^{x}|y'(t)-z'(t)|\mathrm{d}t= \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\left|y(t)-z(t)\right|}{\sqrt{t}}\mathrm{d}t$. Hence, $y-z=0$ by Grönwall lemma.